# SQL do i use Subquery or what?

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, subquery

ok so i have 3 tables :

[image: see this image]

i need to return which cars have received fixing more than 150 times

thanks in advance :)

Comment: "or what" is the answer to your question. Try joining the tables and adding group by and a having

Comment: i just cant get it to work im literally making biger mess every time

Comment: You will need to start paying attention in class. Find a tutorial on select & joins. Then group by and count.  Then on  having. There is no point in is telling you the answer you have to learn in stages

Comment: Welcome to SO :) StackOverflow users are not there to do everything in your place. You should edit your question and explain what you've tried so far. It will show that you made some efforts to look for answers by yourself first : [How do I ask a good question ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And always take advice with a splash of skepticism. Heck, I make mistakes, too.

Answer (score 1):

The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT T1.Car, COUNT(t3.*)
FROM
Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.table2ID
JOIN Table3 T3 on T3.Id = T2.table3Id
GROUP BY T1.Car
Order by T1.Car
```

Yes you can also do a subquery so you would be selecting from table 1 and instead of the count, you would do a subquery with table 2 and table 2 joined back to table 1.

But you can use join. I think they will be more efficient here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using a relational database, Secondly, you happen to have 2 `Dimension` Tables and 1 `FACT` table

The dimension tables make searching the `FACT` table easier, though this only is valid if you need a characteristic from those `DIMENSION` tables that you cannot get in the `FACT` table (such as `[type]` of fixes).

Since you want the raw results of Cars and their number of repairs, use a `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` Clause in your query. Remember that the `HAVING` clause is still a `PREDICATE`, so use proper `SARGS`.

```
SELECT CAR_ID, COUNT(*) --or COUNT(CAR_ID), it really does not matter
FROM FACT_TABLE
GROUP BY CAR_ID
HAVING COUNT(FIX_ID) >= 150
```

The `GROUP BY` smashes the table by `CAR_ID` and counts the rows combined in the `COUNT` function while the `HAVING`, begin a predicate, filters the results of the aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, just use two inner joins. And then group by car and count the number of lines.

Comment: is there a way without joins?

Comment: Yes (for inner joins) and _no_. If you wish to work with SQL there is no way to avoid joins. These may be the single most important feature of SQL.